# Hover event on div under absolute positioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is possible to obtain hover event on element, which is under absolute positioned div? That absolute positioned div is child of body element, but that under isn't, so they are not in relationship parent/child. I do drag and drop of that absolute div and i want highlight area, where user can drop, when mouse it's under that area.

```
enter code here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rv8kp/

Comment: Very interesting question. Have you tried something?

Comment: SebastianG: yes wait, i try to do jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer would be no, you cant. But.. there is a workaround

You can add `mousemove` event handler for the whole document. Inside the handler you check if mouse position is in the area of the element you need to hover.

```
var $pos = $("#pos");
var top = $pos.offset().top;
var left = $pos.offset().left;
var bottom = top + $pos.height();
var right = left + $pos.width();

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {

    if (e.pageY >= top && e.pageY <= bottom && e.pageX >= left && e.pageX <= right)
        $pos.addClass("hover");
    else
        $pos.removeClass("hover");
});
```

you can view full working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kcy7/)